# On .click the body should fade out, but it doesn't

Tags: jquery, redirect, fadeout

Hello stackoverflower,

I have a little problem with the following javascript on my page. 
The goal is, that it fade's out the body and then goes in 'parent.history.back', using Jquery. But somehow I don't get it to work.

Here's what I tried for the body to fade out.

```
$("body").fadeOut(500, redirectPage);
```

and it should go together with this here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.back').click(function(){
    parent.history.back();
    return false;
});
});
```

Can someone help me, putting these to together, so they work? 
Thanks for the one who saves my day!

Comment: Have you defined the function `redirectPage`? Your `history.back` call should go inside that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.back').click(function(){
    $('body').fadeOut(500, function() {
        parent.history.back();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.back').click(function(){
    $("body").fadeOut(500, function(){
        history.back();
        return false;
    });
});
```